# How to display jquery auto complete result as links

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a product database from which I have to show the product title as result in jquery auto complete searching. I want to show the search listing as link so that when user click on the result he will be redirect to the product description page. I am using codeigniter currently its working fine and show searching result perfectly but I don't know how I can show them in links. Check my controller, model and view code below:

**My database fields**
`prod_id, prod_name, prod_title, prod_description`

**Controllers/product.php**

```
public function searchItems()
{
        $srch = $this->main_model->searchProduct($this->input->get('term', TRUE));
        $status = $srch['status'];
        if ($status == 1)
        {
            $rslt = $srch['rs'];
            for ($i=0; $i < count($rslt); $i++) { 
              $farr[] = $rslt[$i][0];
            }
            echo json_encode($farr);
        }
        else
        {
            $rslt = array('No result found.');
            echo json_encode($rslt);
        }
}
```

**Model Code**

```
public function searchProduct($searchTerm)
{
  $this->db->like('title', $searchTerm, 'both');
  $srchData = $this->db->get('seller_item');
  if ($srchData->num_rows() > 0)
  {
    $rsult = $srchData->result();
    foreach ($rsult as $value)
    {
      $prodName[] = array($value->title);
    }
    return array("status"=>1, "rs"=>$prodName);
  }
  else {
    return array("status"=>0);
  }
}
```

**View Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Autocomplete textbox using jQuery, PHP and MySQL by CodexWorld</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
  source: "http://localhost:8888/store/test/search/?"
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="skills">Skills: </label>
<input id="skills">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to create link like this format:

`http://localhost:8888/store/product/view/8`

So that user can redirect to the detail page when he/she click on the specific search result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the `_renderItem` option provided by default. Below is the sample.

```
$("#project").autocomplete({
    source: "http://localhost:8888/store/test/search/?"
})
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
        .append( '<div><a href="http://localhost:8888/store/product/view/' + item.id + '"></a>' + item.desc + '</div>' )
        .appendTo(ul);
         //Assuming here your item contains product id and description
};
```

Here is their official documentation on **[custom data](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)**

I would like to suggest here to use relative url instead of absolute url, since production might not have localhost instead it will have domain name.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: can you help me in Magento I have question?

Comment: @muditmehrotra Sorry to say but Magneto is out of my boundary.. My area of expertise is on different platform.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a url property to each object in the source array and then set window.location to that URL when the user selects an item like:

```
var source = [ { value: "www.foo.com",
             label: "Spencer Kline"
           },
           { value: "www.example.com",
             label: "James Bond"
           },
           ...
         ];
```

Than use the select method to redirect to the 'value' like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: source,
        select: function( event, ui ) { 
            window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        }
    });
});
```